# Override of iOS HTML fullscreen video controls possible (iPhone, iPad)?

Tags: ios, video, controls, fullscreen

I need to remove/hide the +/- 15s buttons and the video timeline to avoid skipping parts of a video file in fullscreen.

Is it possible to somehow override the default appearance?